# Django CSRF token won't show

Tags: django, django-templates, django-csrf

Here's the relevant snippet of HTML in the template:

```
    <form action="/submit_text/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% include "backbone/form_errors.html" %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Here is my `settings.py` `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` declaration:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ( 
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

The CSRF token simply doesn't show, causing a

> Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to pass the `RequestContext` in your `render_to_response` for the context processors to actually be run.

```
 from django.template import RequestContext

 context = {}
 return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                           context,
                           context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

the new [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut (django 1.3+) will do it for you:

```
 from django.shortcuts import render

 context = {}
 return render(request, 'my_template.html', context)
```

Comment: Very helpful! I had a custom template tag, so I had to specify `@register.simple_tag(takes_context = True)` and then `return render_to_string('template.html', {}, context_instance=context)`.

Answer (score 5):

While there is a checked answer, I want to point out that writing `context_instance....` gets really annoying. I find this useful...especially with `forms`

```
context.update(csrf(request))
```