# Django DeleteView with GET request

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I've seen this Q&A:

[Django DeleteView without confirmation template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475324/django-deleteview-without-confirmation-template)

and this one:

[Django CSRF token won't show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610768/django-csrf-token-wont-show)

but that doesn't address the built-in intended functionality of the DeleteViewm CBV when issued a GET. From the docs (emphasis mine):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView

"If this view is fetched via **GET**, it will display a confirmation page that should contain a form that POSTs to the same URL."

The problem is that as I understand it, the rendered template in response to a GET will not included the `RequestContext` necessary to include the `{% csrf_token %}` in the mentioned POST form. I worked around it for the time being by overriding the `get()` method so that it uses `render()` to return the page, since it automatically includes the appropriate context.

How do I maximally leverage the `DeleteView`? What am I doing wrong that I need to implement the following code in my view?

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
    return render(self.request,'mainapp/template_confirm_delete.html')
```